# How to develop for iPhone OS 3.1.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Strange thing happened: My old 2.2.1 version iPod works perfectly with Xcode. Now I got a new one with 3.1.2 installed. Xcode complains that it can't develop for 3.1.2, but instead it can do so for:

```
Xcode Supported iPhone OS Versions
3.1.1 (7C145)
3.1 (7C144)
3.0.1 (7A400)
3.0
2.2.1
2.2
2.1.1
2.1
2.0.2 (5C1)
2.0.1 (5B108)
2.0 (5A347)
2.0 (5A345)
```

Now what can I do about it? I have Snow Leopard and Xcode 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update your version of XCode. Go to http://developer.apple.com/iphone/ and download the new SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need the new iphone SDK 3.2 beta available from developer.apple.com today.